# Problems with automatic weights when rigging

Tags: rigging, bones

Just created a simple character with a head, body, and legs. But when I use try to rig it, the joints get distorted. I tried to use empty groups (since it worked in 2d), but the parts wouldn't move.

Normal/Resting Position:

[image]

[image: The tree:]

When I move a model:

[image]
[image]

Weight Paints:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the file:
https://github.com/daarush/BlendersTestings

Please tell me if you cannot access it.

Comment: If you want your model to behave as rigid parts please state so.  If you want you model to behave as organic rubbery flexible parts please state so.  I am guessing at this point.  Please show you model in weight paint mode.

Comment: Please restate [the joints get distorted] clearly.   Again guessing.  Do you mean meshes are intersecting? You probably can consider a tutorial on Armatures and Blender  on the famous website that has a  name that rhymes with noonoob.

Comment: Can you take a look again @atomicbezierslinger.

Comment: Please show your entire screen in weight paint mode.  So we can see bone selected and the associated paint, and whether or not you think the weight is correct.  A full picture of the weight paint mechanism not tiny bits.  A picture with an arrow that indicates ... this area is a problem because ....

Comment: I am new to blender, how do i do a entire screen?

Comment: Keep in mind if this is too tutorial in nature some people will stop writing.  You can capture part of  a screen ... or the whole screen ... You can tell me what mechanism you already used to capture the image.  I would like to see the 3D View and the Vertex Groups all at once.  All your bits and pieces can be deleted from the question

Comment: I will check back in 24 hours  to see if any of the requests put in the comments are satisfied,  if I am able.

Comment: for this kind of character you need to parent With Empty Groups then select a part of your mesh in Edit mode and in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups, assign to the right vertex group

Comment: @moonboots, just looked at the vertex groups, and like atomicbezier was saying (that I have more than 4 parts in total), both of you are correct.

Comment: you guys need to understand I am just got into blender, so please take a look at the file I sent, so you guys can take a look at the way you want.

Comment: Since the head object wears a hood, automatic weighting cannot correctly weight the hood.

Comment: the hood and the head is one mesh

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have 5 pieces rather than 4.  Include both head pieces with parenting to the bone.

Comment: no, it only had one head piece

Comment: I can send the file to you, if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DNR:  Here's your rigged character:

[image]

You have several problems.

1. Each of your four objects is *non-manifold*
2. You shouldn't parent when there are transforms applied to the armature.
3. Your feet bones don't have parents so there's no single bone you can use to move the entire object in pose mode.

Your best bet would be to parent each object to its own bone separately.

Here are the the steps I took to fix the rigging.

1. Undo your current attempt.  For each of the objects:

   - Select the object in *object* mode.
   - go to *Object properties*; open the *Relations* panel and click the x to delete the armature as parent.
   - go to *Modifiers* and delete the armature modifier.
   - go to *Object Data properties* and remove all of the vertex groups.
   - Clear all transforms by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>S</kbd>
2. While you're at it, fix the duplicate vertices.

   - Select the object in *edit* mode, select all of the vertices and remove duplicates by typing <kbd>M</kbd> and selecting *by distance* from the drop down menu.
3. Fix the rig itself

   - Select the rig in *object* mode
   - Make the rest of this easier by going to *Armature Data Properties*; opening the *Viewport Display* panel and selecting *In Front*
   - Clear all transforms by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>S</kbd>
   - Select the rig in *Pose* mode and clear all transforms by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd> to deselect all bones and then <kbd>A</kbd> to select all bones and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>S</kbd> to clear all transforms.
   - Select the rig in *edit* mode.
   - Select each of the leg bones and then select the body bone.
   - Type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>–<kbd>P</kbd> to parent and select *Keep Offset* from the dropdown menu.
4. Finally, you can now parent the objects to the bones.  For each object:

   - Select the object
   - Shift Select the Armature
   - Enter *pose* mode.
   - Select the bone the object should be parented to.
   - Type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>–<kbd>P</kbd> and select bone from the drop down menu.